# Google Cloud Dataproc - Spark and Hadoop Version

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataproc

In the Google Cloud Dataproc beta what are the versions of Spark and Hadoop?

What version of Scala is Spark compiled for?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the [official announcement](http://googlecloudplatform.blogspot.be/2015/09/Google-Cloud-Dataproc-Making-Spark-and-Hadoop-Easier-Faster-and-Cheaper.html):

> Today, we are launching with clusters that have Spark 1.5 and Hadoop
>   2.7.1.

Comment: Great news here.  I think Google really needed this to 'compete' with the `spark-ec2` script.  There are a few `spark-gce` scripts out there but only for older versions.  This should be added to the docs.

Comment: Do you know what version of Scala?

Comment: Scala version 2.10.4 with Spark 1.5.

Answer (score 2):

[Current Spark version info is listed in the docs](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/dataproc-versions). Spark 2.1.0 uses Scala 2.11.

Answer (score 0):

The version of Spark depends on the [version of DataProc](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/versioning/dataproc-versions?hl=en_US&_ga=2.138984627.-1493414212.1524456046&_gac=1.50610651.1539966911.CjwKCAjwgabeBRBuEiwACD4R5nv1vRGGSxvB_f31R-V-LMgbgy2lhRGbwJp7mIJw7hzlV6RC9ggN6hoCKfkQAvD_BwE) in use, currently it uses Data Proc v1.2 and it has

Spark: 2.2.1
Scala: 2.11.8

There are predefined [initialization scripts](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/dataproc-initialization-actions) for DataProc for many frameworks including Kafka which has the following versions:

Kafka: 2.11.0.10.1
Kafka Client: 0.10.1